# How to save incoming messages in encrypted format

Tags: android

I need to receive sms from this a particular number, encrypt it and later sent in the inbox. This way my message is protected from reading by anyone else who handles my phone.

Comment: You need to specify your question.

Comment: @ V.J actually i want then when i receive sms from this no  e.g "1222xx" then i will encrypt its text and after that it should saved in my inbox with real sender name etc...

Comment: Edited the question to be clear. Please delete your comments.

Comment: No, first I will make your question look more appropriate for this forum. Else you will get -ve votes and the question will be closed by the moderator. You must read the FAQ. Your question was horribly formatted, no grammar, no punctuation, no capitalization, language completely unclear. I helped make your question, a question. Dont defend your badly put question here, learn instead. Delete your comments. Dont waste time and space of SO. Its a high quality Q&A site, keep it that way. Again, delete all your comments, and so will I.

Comment: Keep in mind that you already had -ve votes, I voted it up since your question was badly put, but you did have a valid question. So you should be thankful to me instead of explaining to me what I should and should not do.

Comment: ok ! i got it, i will be

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put("address", "123456789");
values.put("body", "foo bar");
getContentResolver().insert(Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox"), values);
```

I hope this helps

Comment: have you included  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SMS"></uses-permission>

Comment: Yes its a simple way of doing it.I tried it on emulator and it worked.

Comment: error suggest you should include android.permission.READ-SMS.

Comment: Yeah i have included READ_SMS and it is working 100 %, so many thanks @ paresh Mayani u done a great Job, really you are a Techi man.